# Visual Studio 2015 fail to load package because Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 fail to load

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I've built a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2015 and 2017. I've developed it with 2017 and everything works great on 2017.

When I install it on VS 2015 I get an error message saying it failed to load my package. In the visual studio `ActivityLog.xml` file I see the following error.

How can I enable both VS 2015 and 2017 to run the extension?

```
CreateInstance failed for package [MainWindowPackage]
Source: 'mscorlib' 
Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo) at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the error message, your extension dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0, which is a VS 2017 assembly. So it is not contained in your VS 2015.

If you want your extension supports multiple versions of Visual Studio, you need to let your VSPackage to using **only the features of the earliest version of Visual Studio** that you support and program your VSPackage to adapt to the version of Visual Studio in which it is running. You could read this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/choosing-between-shared-and-versioned-vspackages

And you also could reference the document that [Supporting Multiple Versions of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/supporting-multiple-versions-of-visual-studio).

The custom installation path is "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\". Please check your extension path to make sure the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You should reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.**14**.0 and other assemblies from VS 2015 in your extension to support both VS 2015/2017.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue for quite some time.

```
CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.Data.SAPClient.Design.SAPDataProviderPackage]
Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\$=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\3.0\InstallPath$Microsoft.Data.SAPClient.Design.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I had to open Visual Studio Installer, find this VS Component (BizTalk) and remove it.